# ZEND framework Google Calendar Shutdown - php web app

Tags: php, zend-framework, calendar

As of November 17, 2014 Google announced they shutdown the google calendar API v1,v2.

See this link:
http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/06/calendar-gdata-api-google-calendar.html

A couple years ago we built a php web form to input data into the calendar with ZEND framework.

With the current code now not working and getting this error.

Error: Expected response code 200, got 403
Forbidden
Error 403

This is very frustrating because we need this application working on the website, its basically the whole point of even visiting the site in the first place.

The php form was pretty simple. Basically a visitor would enter their zip code, then choose a day and time that is displayed from the "availability calendar" on their gmail calendar account. There was also two more custom calendar that was for booked online, and internal booking purposes. Once someone completed the steps including input forms with their contact information and hitting submit the "availability calendar" would be updated on their site as booked and the google calendar itself.

It would also send en email notifying you booked.

I am not personally familiar with ZEND and Google Cal APIv3. I have a level of understanding with php/css/etc but not deep enough to go through the entire upgrade process.

I was hoping maybe it was something pretty easy and someone here on StackOverflow that has a strong knowledge with this material can help me with.

It seems I have read their forums and many, many, many people are frustrated with the shutdown of v1,v2.

Would I need to upgrade the ZEND framework? Currently it is 1.11.3, or can I leave that alone.

I have read that the point of v3 is to make writing the code easier, so maybe this isn't to difficult of a task... Here is the code on the first step.

```
        <?php

        function setEnvironment() {
            session_start();
            date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        }

        setEnvironment();

        function setup() {
            set_include_path("/var/www/vhosts/mydomainexample.com/httpdocs/");
            require_once("Zend/Loader.php");
            Zend_Loader::loadClass("Zend_Gdata");
            Zend_Loader::loadClass("Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin");
            Zend_Loader::loadClass("Zend_Gdata_Calendar");
        }   

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                                              //
        //  CONNECT TO GOOGLE CALENDAR                  //
        //                                              //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function connect() {
            global $service;

            $user = "mygmailexample@gmail.com";
            $pass = "mypasswordexample";

            $serviceName = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
            $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $serviceName);
            $service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                                              //
        //  CREATE EVENT AND ADD TO CALENDAR            //
        //                                              //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function bookAppointment() {
            global $service;

            $title = "ONLINE BOOKING: " . $_SESSION["fullName"] . " , " . $_SESSION["townCity"];

            $content .= "Name: " . $_SESSION["fullName"] . "\n\n";
            $content .= "Requested Time: " . date("l M jS g:i A",$_SESSION["s"]) . " - " . date("g:i A",$_SESSION["e"]) . "\n\n";
            $content .= "Home Phone: " . $_SESSION["homePhone"] . "\n\n";
            $content .= "Email: " . $_SESSION["emailAddress"] . "\n\n";

            $content .= "Address: \n\n" . $_SESSION["streetAddress"] . "\n";
            $content .= "" . $_SESSION["townCity"] . " ";
            $content .= "" . $_SESSION["zipCode"] . "\n\n";

            $content .= "" . $_SESSION["jobDescription"] . "\n\n";

            $event = $service->newEventEntry();
            $event->title = $service->newTitle($title);
            $event->content = $service->newContent($content);
            $when = $service->newWhen();
            $when->startTime = date(DateTime::RFC3339,$_SESSION["s"]);
            $when->endTime = date(DateTime::RFC3339,$_SESSION["e"]);
            $event->when = array($when);

            $newEvent = $service->insertEvent($event,"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/o8d31pro7mbgbi2g93acsluhn8@group.calendar.google.com/private/full");
            $eventUri = $newEvent->id->text;

            $to      = "example@example.com";
            $subject = $title;
            $message = $content;
            $headers = 'From: ' . $_SESSION["emailAddress"] . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $_SESSION["emailAddress"] . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            $to      = $_SESSION["emailAddress"];
            $subject = "BOOKED:";
            $message = "Thank you for booking an appointment with example! We look forward to seeing you and may contact you one more time to confirm before we travel to your location.\n\n" . $content;
            $headers = "From: example <example@example.com>\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: Lalaland Tan <example@example.com>\r\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                                              //
        //  GET SCHEDULE AND AVAILABILITY FROM GOOGLE   //
        //                                              //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function getSchedule() {
            global $service, $timeSlotsByDay;

            $query = $service->newEventQuery();
            $query->setVisibility("private");
            $query->setProjection("full");
            $query->setOrderby("starttime");
            $query->setSortOrder('ascending');
            $query->setStartMin(date(DateTime::RFC3339));
            $query->setStartMax(date(DateTime::RFC3339,(time()+2678400)));
            $query->setSingleEvents("true");
            $query->setMaxResults(999);

            $query->setUser("exampleurl@group.calendar.google.com");

            try {
                $internalBookings = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
            } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $query->setUser("exampleurl@group.calendar.google.com");

            try {
                $onlineBookings = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
            } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $query->setUser("exampleurl@group.calendar.google.com");

            try {
                $availableSlots = $service->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
            } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $timeSlotsByDay = array();

            foreach ($availableSlots as $timeSlot) {

                $slotStart = strtotime($timeSlot->when[0]->starttime);
                $slotEnd = strtotime($timeSlot->when[0]->endtime);
                $available = true;

                foreach ($internalBookings as $event) {
                    if ( $available ) {
                        $bookingStart = strtotime($event->when[0]->starttime);
                        $bookingEnd = strtotime($event->when[0]->endtime);

                        if ( ( $bookingStart >= $slotStart ) && ( $bookingStart < $slotEnd ) ) {
                            $available = false;
                        }

                        if ( ( $bookingEnd > $slotStart ) && ( $bookingEnd <= $slotEnd ) ) {
                            $available = false;
                        }

                        if ( ( $bookingStart <= $slotStart ) && ( $bookingEnd >= $slotEnd ) ) {
                            $available = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach ($onlineBookings as $event) {
                    if ( $available ) {
                        $bookingStart = strtotime($event->when[0]->starttime);
                        $bookingEnd = strtotime($event->when[0]->endtime);

                        if ( ( $bookingStart >= $slotStart ) && ( $bookingStart < $slotEnd ) ) {
                            $available = false;
                        }

                        if ( ( $bookingEnd > $slotStart ) && ( $bookingEnd <= $slotEnd ) ) {
                            $available = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $timeSlotsByDay[date("Ymd",strtotime($timeSlot->when[0]->starttime))][] = array("start"=>$slotStart,"end"=>$slotEnd,"available"=>$available);
            }

        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                                              //
        //  STORE FORM DATA IN SESSION                  //
        //                                              //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function sessTimeSlot() {
            $_SESSION["s"] = $_GET["s"];
            $_SESSION["e"] = $_GET["e"];
        }

        function sessJobDetails() {
            $_SESSION["fullName"] = $_POST["fullName"];
            $_SESSION["homePhone"] = $_POST["homePhone"];
            $_SESSION["emailAddress"] = $_POST["emailAddress"];

            $_SESSION["streetAddress"] = $_POST["streetAddress"];
            $_SESSION["townCity"] = $_POST["townCity"];
            $_SESSION["zipCode"] = $_POST["zipCode"];

            $_SESSION["jobDescription"] = $_POST["jobDescription"];

        }



        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use Zend anymore to list, add, delete event. You have to use google api v3.
Here is an example of class you can use to manage events:
[Authentification Zend Gdata (403 forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011264/authentification-zend-gdata-403-forbidden/27034888#27034888)