# Authentification Zend Gdata (403 forbidden)

Tags: zend-framework, gdata

Is there already ANY solution how to insert/edit/delete events in google Calendar using Zend Gdata Framework.
Since November 17 it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First you have to follow this step:
http://cornempire.net/2012/01/08/part-2-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/

When it's done you can use my class : !! Curl has to be enable on your server.

```
class gcalendar{
    private $cal_id;
    //To get credentials follow this steps ==> http://cornempire.net/2012/01/08/part-2-oauth2-and-configuring-your-application-with-google/
    private $client_secret='to_change';//TO CHANGE
    private $refresh_token='to_change';//TO CHANGE
    private $client_id='to_change';//TO CHANGE
    public  $spindle='+01:00';
    private $token;

    public function __construct($cal_id){
        $this->token=$this->get_access_token();
        $this->cal_id=$cal_id;
    }

    //Retourne un token
    private function get_access_token(){
        $tokenURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
        $postData = array(
            'client_secret'=>$this->client_secret,
            'grant_type'=>'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token'=>$this->refresh_token,
            'client_id'=>$this->client_id
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $tokenReturn = curl_exec($ch);
        $token = json_decode($tokenReturn);

        $accessToken = $token->access_token;
        return $accessToken;
    }

    //liste tous les events sur la période définit en param
    public function list_events($start_date,$end_date){
        return $this->execute('list_events',false,array('start_date'=>$start_date,'end_date'=>$end_date));
    }

    //Récupere l'event ayant l'id passer en param
    public function get_event($event_id){
        return $this->execute('get_event',false,array('event_id'=>$event_id));
    }

    //Ajoute un event !!Attention$_data doit respecter une certaine syntaxe voir plus bas fonction create_args!
    public function add_event($_data){
        $args=$this->create_args($_data);
        return($this->execute('add_event',$args));
    }

    //Modifie un rdv (heures, titre ou contenu).
    public function update_event($event_id,$_data){
        $ev=json_decode($this->get_event($event_id));
        $_data['sequence']=$ev->sequence+1;
        $args=$this->create_args($_data);
        return($this->execute('update_event',$args,array('event_id'=>$event_id)));
    }

    //Supprime un event
    public function delete_event($event_id){
        return $this->execute('delete_event',false,array('event_id'=>$event_id));
    }

    /*
    **  $_data=array( 
                !start_date =>  Date de début de l'event au format Y-m-d
                !start_time =>  Heure de début de l'event au format HH:ii
                !end_date   =>  Date de fin de l'event Y-m-d
                !end_time   =>  Heure de fin de l'event HH:ii
                summary     =>  Titre de l'event (title)
                description =>  Description de l'event
                sequence    =>  Sequence de l'event (C'est un numéro à incrémenter à chaque update de l'event). Obligatoire lors d'un update.
            )
        Les champs avec un ! sont obligatoires!
    **
    */
    private function create_args($_data){
        $_args=array(   'start'     =>  array('dateTime'=>$_data['start_date']."T".$_data['start_time'].":00.000".$this->spindle),
                        'end'       =>  array('dateTime'=>$_data['end_date']."T".$_data['end_time'].":00.000".$this->spindle));
        unset($_data['start_date']);
        unset($_data['start_time']);
        unset($_data['end_date']);
        unset($_data['end_time']);
        foreach($_data as $key=>$value){
            $_args[$key]=$value;
        }
        return json_encode($_args);
    }

    //execute les requetes curl adaptée selon le type ($type_exe)
    private function execute($type_exe,$args=false,$opt=false){
        switch ($type_exe){
            case 'list_events':
                $request='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.urlencode($this->cal_id).'/events?timeMax='.urlencode($opt['end_date'].'T23:59:59.000'.$this->spindle).'&timeMin='.urlencode($opt['start_date'].'T00:00:01.000'.$this->spindle);
                $session = curl_init($request);
            break;
            case 'get_event':
                $request='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.urlencode($this->cal_id).'/events/'.$opt['event_id'];
                $session = curl_init($request);
            break;
            case 'add_event':
                $request='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.urlencode($this->cal_id).'/events';
                $session = curl_init($request);
                curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            break;
            case 'update_event':
                $request =  'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.urlencode($this->cal_id).'/events/'.$opt['event_id'];
                $session = curl_init($request);
                curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            break;
            case 'delete_event':
                $request='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'.urlencode($this->cal_id).'/events/'.$opt['event_id'];
                $session = curl_init($request);
                curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            break;
        }
        if($args){
            curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args); 
        }
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:  application/json','Authorization:  Bearer ' . $this->token,'X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  My_company'));
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session); 
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And this is how you can use it

```
//How to use the class:
$gcal=new gcalendar('**calendar_id**');//TO CHANGE
// Add an event 
$result=$gcal->add_event(array('start_date'=>'2014-11-20','start_time'=>'12:00','end_date'=>'2014-11-20','end_time'=>'14:00','summary'=>'My event','description'=>'The desc of my event'));

//List events between two dates
    // $result=$gcal->list_events('2014-11-01','2014-11-30');

//update an event with ID
    // $result=$gcal->update_event('ID_OF_EVENT',array('start_date'=>'2014-11-20','start_time'=>'12:00','end_date'=>'2014-11-20','end_time'=>'14:00','summary'=>'Rdv banane','description'=>'Ceci est une banane'));

//Delete an event with ID
// $result=$gcal->delete_event('ID_OF_EVENT');

//Display result
$res=json_decode($result);
print_r($res);
```

Hope it will help. If you have any question...

Comment: Please post a part of the answer, not just links. You don't have to copy paste the whole thing, but just to sum up it's content, because links can go down and future user would love to be opinted to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

//How to use the class:

```
$gcal=new gcalendar('**your_mail_adress**');//TO CHANGE
```

It's not your mail adress here but your calendar id