# Getting "Forbidden Error 403" on Google Calendar(s) using Zend_Gdata_Calendar()

Tags: zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I have an embedded script running on the home page of one of my sites that pulls a selected list of events on our Google Calendars and lists them on the page. I have been running this script, without change or revision, since about 2011.

Yesterday (maybe the day before) the script started throwing an error `Forbidden Error 403`.

**Here is a snippet of the script:**

```
$ctz = 'America/Los_Angeles';
$calendarID[] = 'example.com_abcdefghijklmnop1234567890@group.calendar.google.com'; //Dept 1 Events
$calendarID[] = 'example.com_klmnopqrstuvwxyz0987654321@group.calendar.google.com'; //Dept 2 Events
/*...*/
$eventArray = buildEventList($calendarID, $ctz);


function buildEventList($calendarID=NULL,$ctz=NULL) {

    require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Uri_Http');

    $gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar();
    $query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();

    try {
        /*...*/
    }

    catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        $return = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $return;

}
```

**The following error message is showing as a result of the catch{}:**

```
Expected response code 200, got 403
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Forbidden</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any ideas on why this started happening or how to resolve?

Notes:
I logged into each of my Google Calendars and nothing on their settings have changed. They are still shared publicly and the ID's have not changed -- I verified everything inside Google Account.

Learnings through continued research:
I think I may need a Google Developer Key -- (1) not sure how to get one and (2) continuing to research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since November 17 you can't use google API V1 or API V2 anymore. Zend Gdata use google API V2. So, you can't use zend anymore to get events. You have to use google library or use your own class. You can see an example of google api V3 class without google library: [Authentification Zend Gdata (403 forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011264/authentification-zend-gdata-403-forbidden/27034888#27034888)

Comment: Thanks @Aldwen. (Here's the article https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php not found